# PHP Passing Array Through Argument

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I'm trying to work with the PayPal API in PHP but I'm having a problem with passing arrays through function arguments. I've been watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD1dOWIABe0). If you look at around 21:00 you can see them writing most of their code. I'm having problems with lines 34 and 59:

```
<?php
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;

require 'start.php';

if(!isset($_POST['product'], $_POST['price'])) {
    echo "Product or price not set";
    die();
}

$product = $_POST['product'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$shipping = 2.00;
$total = $price + $shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item->setName('test')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
    ->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($total)
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($item)
    ->setDescription('Testing')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=true')
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/pay.php?success=false');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

try {
    $payment->create($paypal);
} catch (PayPalConnectionException $e) {
    echo $e->getData();

}

echo $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

With this code I'm using:

```
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);
```

And:

```
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
->setPayer($payer)
->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
->setTransactions([$transaction]);
```

To pass in arrays into the methods, as seen in the video. However this is causing the page to not load. If I change my code to this:

```
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item));
```

And:

```
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
->setPayer($payer)
->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
->setTransactions(array($transaction));
```

Then I get a PayPal error which I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019748/php-paypal-api-validation-error) but no one seems to know the answer. Has the syntax for passing an array through a method argument changed since that video tutorial was made? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The short syntax for arrays (`$array = [1,2,3];`) was [added in PHP 5.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays). If you have an earlier version of PHP you'll need to use the longer `$array = array(1,2,3);` syntax.

**But** PHP 5.3 was [end-of-lifed in 2014](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), 5.4 last year, and 5.5 only has security fixes for the next 13 days. You should strongly consider upgrading if you're not already on 5.6 or 7.